# Explore source control files changes with color decoration in Visual Studio Code

Tags: git, editor

I have installed visual Studio code 1.53.2 in my system and open the project from source control to add and modify the files. When I pull new changes from the  branch then modified files are not showing in decoration color in explore. while all setting regarding this is okay in setting. So please help me someone to resolved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check first if:

- git is recognized (type git version in the VSCode console)
- git is (if not recognized) set in `git.path` user setting
- the files modified are indeed in a Git repository

For the last point, switch to command line (CMD) and type:

```
cd c:\path\to\modified\files
git status
```

Comment: I have tested . git is recognized. can you explain me in details

Comment: @user2765275 Did you open a CMD and cd to the parent folder of the modified files to do a `git status`?